# Gray bearded newbie needs php guidance

Tags: php

I've created a boardgame and there is one element I can create manually but it is a very time consuming task so after much research I decided to learn php to automate the task. This is what I want to do and would appreciate any guidance towards specific learning resources that might help me in this task.

Create 4 10 x 10 tables with each cell being sequentially numbered from 0=99.

Ideally the numbering will be inside the cells but if I really had to I could use grid coordinates instead

I then want to randomly populate the cells, in each table one at a time, with two letter strings from an existing array. e.g table1 0TE 1GR 2MN 3TE 4KN....

I then want to be able to print the tables

BTW I choose php because I want players to be able to create their own tables online, also it will, in the long term, be the most beneficial to me as I will never be a professional programmer.

Cheers Don

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, but this site is for questions that can be answered in a succinct and objective way. You must ask more precise and focused questions.

Comment: 43 is hardly old. I should downvote for false advertising ;). As for the rest...you might be best starting with task one on your own, and when you hit a stumbling block, coming here for an answer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, you might want to have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: You learned to drive 30 years ago… when you were only 13! OMG, that's illegal in my country! ;)

Comment: agree that question is hard to answer. however, learning to ask the right question is part of the game, ie requires breaking down the problem into managable subparts which is a lot what programming is about as well. right now, it's not even so clear how these tables really are supposed to look like. how about you describe your problem with two tables which are 2x2 and give some examples of valid and invalid results. then try to describe how you want to get those. either you have a problem describing that procedure -> concrete SO-compatible question or you run into trouble programming it->dito

Comment: If 43 is old, I'm a prehistoric relic (I wrote my first programs over 40 years ago), and some of the best programmers I know are ancient fossils.

Comment: Jeeze you lot are easy to rile up. The main reason I posted the whole thing was because I thought a similar script might already exist. I'd look like a moron if it did. Or who knows maybe it is impossible to do what I want. Or maybe a hobbyist isn't capable of learning the necessary things to make such a programme.

Comment: 13 isn't young, my cousin was driving his Nana around when he was nine

Comment: @don: The edits made the question answerable, but I have one question: Why would you want to give each cell a number, before writing them over with the array items? Because PHP runs server-side, the output will be no different in the end if you were to skip that step.

Comment: Do you already have some programming experience? Apart from tutorials, I think you'll learn a lot by reading a good PHP book. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90924/what-is-the-best-php-programming-book

Answer (score 1):

First, a superb PHP reference is the [**online manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/).

The grid could most easily be handled by making each box a `<div>` or, since this **is** tabular data a `<td>` in a table. To achieve this in php use a [**for()**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) loop or two.

You'll have to do both the numbering and the insertion of the random strings inside of this `for()` loop.

To pick random elements from an array use, [**array_rand()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php). ( [info on arrays in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.array.php) ).

You'll probably want to do your styling with CSS.

If you do not use HTML / CSS, and decide to just use PHP output in a non HTML environment, then you'll want to make use of [**the plethora of PHP string functions**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php). [**str_pad()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) and [**printf()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) are especially useful for formatting your output in these situations.

Finally, for sharing / testing code [**Codepad**](http://codepad.org/)  & [**Codepad Viper**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/) are fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

First, please read the comment I left.

Second, since you asked for resources:

http://www.php.net/ - The Mothership

http://devzone.zend.com/node/view/id/627 - Old but still usable

There's your start.

Answer (score 0):

how the code would be written greatly depends on where this array of 2 letter strings you have is coming from...but here is a self-contained example with some randomly generated 2 letter strings:

```
$strings = range('A','Z');
for ($a = 0;$a < 100; $a++) {
  $array[] = $strings[rand(0,25)] . $strings[rand(0,25)];
} 

for ($table = 1; $table <= 4; $table++) {
  $count = 0;
  $tarray = $array;
  echo "table " . $table . "<br/>";
  echo "<table border='1'>";
  for ($x = 0; $x < 10; $x++) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($y = 0; $y < 10; $y++) {
      $alpha = array_splice($tarray,rand(0,count($tarray)-1),1);  
      echo "<td>" . $count . $alpha[0] . "</td>";
      $count++;
    }
    echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
}
```

could shorten this with completely random generated 2 letter strings but i particularly wanted to show use of array_splice() if you have an actual array of 100 (or 400?) 2 letter strings and wanted to do a "pick once" deal, where you randomly select it and can only use it on one cell.

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/mW2nv0 ... btw, if you have an array of 100 (or 400) 2 letter string, and you wanted to do a "pick once" deal, `shuffle()` would probably be simpler - http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php